# Equally space two divs within a parent div with one div with a position of fixed

Tags: css, reactjs

**GOAL:** Fill black div with equally spaced & sized blue and red divs.

Here is a picture of what renders on the webpage:

[image]

Here is the code that renders this image on the webpage:

```js
<div className="dashboard">
      <div className="dashboard__container">
        <div className="dash__left">
          <Link to="/add-product">
            <button>Add Product</button>
          </Link>
          {products.map((product) => (
            <div className="product__container">
              <Product
                image={product.imageUrl}
                description={product.description}
                name={product.name}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="dash__right">
          <div className="phone__wrapper">
            <div className="phone__container">
              {products.map((product) => (
                <div className="product__container">
                  <ProductsOnPhone
                    image={product.imageUrl}
                    description={product.description}
                    name={product.name}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the css that stles the page:

```
.dashboard__container {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dash__left {
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.dash__right {
  background-color: brown;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.phone__wrapper {
  border: 5px solid green;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 450px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I think there may be something off with the `width` property in the css. I thought my `display: flex` and `justify content` between would work but didn't.

Comment: have you tried changing the phone__wrapper position to absolute?

Comment: @Al_Milligan Yes, already tried doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because `.dashboard__container`, doesn't fill 100% of the site?
What happens if you give `.dashboard__container {width: 100%;}` ?

Also, if you want to fill the black space with the red and blue box, then I believe you need to use `justify-content: stretch;`